# Should I include parentheses in method expressions in <from-action> of navigation cases?

Tags: el, methodexpression

I will perform the 1Z0-896 exam (Java EE 6 JavaServer Faces Developer Certified Expert), and I'm reading the book Core JavaServer Faces and official documentation. As much as I have tried not yet found the answer to a question, what is the difference using the following excerpts from the  of navigation cases in faces-config.xml:

***#{myBean.method()} or #{myBean.method}***

I would like to know the correct way to use the method in the tag, it is with parentheses or not?

Comment: Please clear up your question to include what is relevant.

Comment: Did you try which one works?